# PHP ISO 86601 format date?

Tags: php, date, datetime, datetime-format

I'm trying to create a date in this exact format:

```
2022-05-19T02:00:00.000+02:00
```

And I'm doing this:

```php
$todayDate = new DateTime('19-05-2022', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
$todayDate->format(DateTime::ATOM),
```

But the output looks like this:

```
2022-05-19T00:00:00+02:00
```

There's a subtle difference:

```
2022-05-19T02:00:00.000+02:00  <-- wanted
2022-05-19T00:00:00+02:00 <-- the one I got
```

Any way I can get the one I  need?
What format would that be?

Comment: Don't you mean `ISO 8601`?

Comment: it looks like neither that format or ISO8601 have the milisecond precision - you'll have to pass your own format

Comment: Do you really want a time of 02:00.00 from the pure date '19-05-2022' as in the example?

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by [the documentation on `DateTime` constants](https://www.php.net/manual/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.types), you're looking for `DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED` (example: 2005-08-15T15:52:01.000+00:00) rather than `DateTimeInterface::ATOM`, also known as `DateTimeInterface::RFC3339` (exemple: 2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00).

Answer (score 0):

I assume the questioner wants to transfer a pure date ( with the time 00:00 ) to another time zone. He wants to get hours '02'.

If a very specific fixed format is needed, I don't recommend using predefined constants that may no longer exist or may be changed in a future PHP version.

```
$strDate = date_create('19-05-2022', new DateTimeZone('UTC'))
  ->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'))
  ->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP")
;

echo $strDate;
//2022-05-19T02:00:00.000+02:00
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/SBtd4